# Could not find the correct provider above this widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a problem using Flutter Provider...
My flow is like this: After login user id is passed to new widget -> from there it preforms save to db and then it redirects to new widget (Dashboard).

And this is a code of a widget after Login:

```
return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(title),
          ),
          body: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      var user = Provider.of<UserRepository>(context);
                      user.savePreference(user.user.id, "Something");
                      user.navigateToNewPage(Dashboard(), context);
                      print(user.user.id);
                    },
```

This works:

```
user.savePreference(user.user.id, "Something");
```

But this is causing a problem:

```
user.navigateToNewPage(Dashboard(), context);
```

In Dashboard widget I am creating this:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var user = Provider.of<UserRepository>(context);
```

And in UserRepository I have this:

```
class UserRepository with ChangeNotifier {
  User user;
  Status _status = Status.Uninitialized;

  Status get status => _status;
  User get getUser => user;

  UserRepository.instance();

Future<void> navigateToNewPage(Widget page, BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page));
  }
```

I know this topic has already solved questions, but could not find anything suitable to my problem.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

## Provider Scope

```
MaterialApp
 > provider(Screen A)
 > Screen B
```

If `Provider` is instantiated in Screen A, it won't be accessible in Screen B after a `Navigator.push` from A → B.

#### Why?

Because `Provider` is an `InheritedWidget` and `Navigator` uses `MaterialApp context` outside its Screen A `context` scope. (See Details below.)

#### Fix

Moving `Provider` up to a common-parent, `MaterialApp context`, allows both Screen A and B to inherit its state/context.

```
provider(MaterialApp)
 > Screen A
 > Screen B
```

**Example**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// wrap MaterialApp in Provider widget
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ColorModel(), // ← create/init your state model
      child: MaterialApp(
          home: ScreenA()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## Details

#### Provider

- `Provider` is based on `InheritedWidget`. Only **child** widgets can *inherit* parent widget's state.

  - `Provider` needs to be the **root widget** for any widget tree that wants access to your "provided" state object.

#### Navigator

- `Navigator.push(context)` on Screen A **doesn't use** the `context` from Screen A.

  - It uses `context` from `MaterialApp`.
- `Navigator.push(context)` is actually `Navigator.of(context).push`
- `Navigator.of(context)` means: *search up this context hierarchy until you find a context that instantiated a Navigator*

  - A default `Navigator` is instantiated in `MaterialApp`.
  - Unless you explicitly create/use a different `Navigator`, you're using the default.
  - `Navigator`'s `context` is that of `MaterialApp`.
- Screen B will get *that* context (of `MaterialApp`), *not* the context of Screen A.

  - B is a *sibling* of A, not its child.
  - B does not inherit from A, even though it appears "instantiated" inside `context` A.
  - Screen B is a *child* of `MaterialApp` `context`, not of Screen A `context`.
  - `Provider` `context` scope, if defined in Screen A, doesn't cover Screen B

**Screen A → B**

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenB()))
```

is actually:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenB()))
```

which is like:

```
Navigator.of(MaterialApp).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (MaterialAppContext) => ScreenB())
)
```

So Screen B is under `MaterialApp context`, ***not*** under Screen A `context` and therefore has no access to Screen A `Provider` and its `context`.

See [this answer for a code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66486075/2301224) to a similar question about `Provider`.

Comment: how to add multiproviders ?

Comment: /// wrap MaterialApp in Provider widget is worked for me @AliYarKhan i comment multiprovider in the below.

Comment: in that situation,all provider needs to puts in root widget?

Comment: I can't find a valid common father widget except root widget, that's weird

Comment: This Answer should be treated as a standard template for answering any future answers in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 11):

Parameter `context` for Provider.of(context) must be a child of you defined provider.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // !important here, Scaffold.of(context) returns null
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Demo')),
      body: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return FlatButton(
            child: Text('BUTTON'),
            onPressed: () {
              // here, Scaffold.of(context) returns the locally created Scaffold
              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: Text('Hello.')
              ));
            }
          );
        }
      )
    );
  }
```

Official sample: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html

This is my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider<SomeModel>(
        create: (context){
          return SomeModel();
        },
      ),],
      child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context){
        BuildContext rootContext = context;
        return Container(
//Here to use rootContext is safe
//Provider.of<SomeModel>(rootContext, listen: false);
        );
      }),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try extracting part of your widget tree that lies below Scaffold to a separate widget. 
The context you are using now is used to build your top level widget which does not Navigator yet.

The resulting code should look like that:

```
return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(title),
          ),
          body: LoginWidget()
```

```
class LoginWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      var user = Provider.of<UserRepository>(context);
                      user.savePreference(user.user.id, "Something");
                      user.navigateToNewPage(Dashboard(), context);
                      print(user.user.id);
                    },

...

  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 6):

This is how we used with multi providers

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => GeneralProvider(),
      ),
    ],
    child: MaterialApp(
      home: InitPage(),
      onGenerateRoute: MyRouter.generateRoute,
      initialRoute: '/InitPage',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Eray',
    ),
  );
}
}
```

Comment: Hi there, great answer, I just want to expand that in the `providers` array the order of the providers matter!

Answer (score 5):

I imported my Provider from the wrong path:

```
import 'file:///D:/Projects/Flutter/library_app/lib/MyStateManagement/local/temp_management.dart';
```

And when I change the path's import its work for me:

```
import 'package:library_app/MyStateManagement/local/temp_management.dart';
```

And this issue happened to me when I changed the folder of the Provider file.

Comment: Awesome man you just saved my life after more than 6 hours of working I found the the file name is wrong in import

Answer (score 0):

**maybe answer in `DetailScreen`.**

I don't know whether you resolved this problem.but I just have resolved using a parameter.
frist my problem is , I have a `list screen`, a `detail screen`, and a `listBloc`. I provided `listBloc` in `list screen`. like this :

```
class ListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/list_screen';

  ListScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  static Route route(Map<String, dynamic> args) {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => ListScreen(),
      settings: const RouteSettings(name: routeName),
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) =>ListBloc(),
          )
        ]
        child: DetailScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

and , i need to use `listBloc` in `detail screen`'s `BlocBuilder`.

```
class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  // you need a context
  final BuildContext context;

  // get context
  const DetailScreen({
    Key key,
    @required this.context,
  }) : super(key: key);
  
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // get bloc using your context
    final bloc = this.context.read<ListBloc>();
    return BlocBuilder<ListBloc, ListState>(
      // provide your bloc
      bloc: bloc,
      builder: (context, state) {}
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//My main.dart

void main() {
  final MultiBlocProvider multiBlocProvider = MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
        create: (context) => AuthBloc(),
      ),
      BlocProvider<LoadCategoriesBloc>(
        create: (context) => LoadCategoriesBloc(),
      ),
      BlocProvider<LoadCustomersBloc>(
        create: (context) => LoadCustomersBloc(),
      ),
    ],
    child: const MyApp(),
  );
  runApp(multiBlocProvider);
}

//Use above bloc providers for load data.
//quotationCreate.dart
BlocConsumer<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
  listener: (context, state) {
    if (state is AuthSuccessState) {
      context.read<LoadCategoriesBloc>().add(LoadCategoriesAction());
      context.read<LoadCustomersBloc>().add(LoadCustomersAction());
    } else if (state is AuthFailureState) {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/signin');
    }
  },
),
```

I used MultiBlocProvider and with authorication for my code and, then I used providers like the above.

Answer (score 0):

I change  ChangeNotifierProvider to the parent context of the material app and my Navigator.pop(context, true); and Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/home"); started to work

```
 void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<MasterMonitor>(
        create: (context) => MasterMonitor(),
        child: MaterialApp(
            title: 'My APP',
            theme: ThemeData(
              colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
              useMaterial3: true,
            ),
            home: LoginPage(),
            routes: {
              '/login': (BuildContext context) => LoginPage(),
              '/home': (BuildContext context) => HomePage(
                    key: GlobalKey(),
                    //'/about': (BuildContext context) => AboutPage(key: GlobalKey()),
                  )
            }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwqmU.png)
As i am using navigator.push widget in my login page when i run the dart file the error n which the message on screen is written as:Error: Could not find the correct Provider«FavoriteModel above this Consumer Widget
This happens because you used a "BuildContext, that does not include the provider
Eror: Could not find the correct Provider«FavoriteModels above this Consumer«FavoriteModels Widget
This happens because you used a 'BuildContext that does not include.
If anyone knows about it please suggest me the solution.

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    ),
  );
  APICallService.getProduct();
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => FavoriteModel(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => CartProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: const App(),
    ),
  );
}
```