# why is not defined for the type BuildContext

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]  1. this is code flutter flavor
2. I cannot using context for read ex: `context.read(flavorConfiProvider)`

```
var flavorConfigProvider;
  void mainCommand(FlavorConfig config) {
   flavorConfigProvider =  StateProvider((ref) => config);

  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
       child: MyApp()
   ),
  );
 }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final config = context.read(flavorConfigProvider);
    return MaterialApp(
     title:config.state.appTitle,
     theme:config.state.theme,
     home: const MyHomePage(),
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to read provider using context?

Comment: Yes, but context cannot be defined read method.

Comment: You can wrap with provider.

Comment: No brother, It's like as I capture pic my code above

Comment: I think you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57245186/10157127)

Comment: I used on ProviderScope instead provider, one more I see one repo on GitHub they are using the same me and it's working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242510/discussion-between-am-koem-heang-and-yeasin-sheikh).