# Use Provider to update Scaffold from a second screen

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-provider

I want to have a Settings screen where I can choose a color to be returned to the first screen.

I can't get the first screen to update when the Setting screen is closed.

I'm using the Provider as a change notifier. But I can't see how to trigger the update of the first screen. The third button creates an event which updates the screen, but can this be done automatically?

What am I missing...?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
Color bgColor = Colors.yellow[100];

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: MyHomeScreen());
  }
}

class MyHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ColorModel()),
      ],
      child: Consumer<ColorModel>(builder: (context, colorModel, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Thanks for your help :)')),
          body: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
            color: bgColor,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Text('Change background color on this screen'),

                OutlinedButton(
                  style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green[600],
                  ),
                  child:
                  Text('Button1', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    var result = Navigator.push(
                        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen2()));
                    print('>>> Button1-onPressed completed, result=$result');
                  },
                ),


                OutlinedButton(
                  style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green[600],
                  ),
                  child:
                  Text('Choose a colour', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    asyncButton(context);
                    print('>>> Screen1 Button-onPressed completed');
                  },
                ),

                OutlinedButton(
                  style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green[600],
                  ),
                  child:
                  Text('Now try me', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    colorModel.notifyListeners();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  void asyncButton(BuildContext context) async {
    var result = await Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen2()));
    print('>>> asyncButton completed: result = $result');
    bgColor = result;
  }
}

class ColorModel with ChangeNotifier {
  void updateDisplay() {
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  int _value;
  List<String> names = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'];
  List<Color> colors = [Colors.red[100], Colors.green[100], Colors.blue[100]];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ColorModel()),
      ],
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 80,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          title: Center(child: Text('Screen2')),
        ),
        body: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Consumer<ColorModel>(builder: (context, colorModel, child) {
                return DropdownButton(
                  value: _value,
                  hint: Text("Select a color"),
                  focusColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                  onChanged: (int value) {
                    Navigator.pop(context, colors[value]);
                  },
                  items: [
                    DropdownMenuItem(value: 0, child: Text(names[0])),
                    DropdownMenuItem(value: 1, child: Text(names[1])),
                    DropdownMenuItem(value: 2, child: Text(names[2])),
                  ],
                );
              }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Navigator.push` is tricky to use with `Provider`.  It causes a lot of `"Could not find the correct Provider above this Navigator Widget"` errors.  I've explained why in [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66485893/2301224).

Here's a quick overview of your situation:

## Provider Scope

Architecture in question code:

```
MaterialApp
 > provider(Screen A)
 > provider(Screen B)
```

Architecture in solution below:

```
provider(MaterialApp)
 > Screen A
 > Screen B
```

Here's your code sample, shortened up, working with `Provider`, updating the background color on Page 1 from the Page 2.

I've put comments throughout the code to explain changes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

// - global var removed -
// Color bgColor = Colors.yellow[100];

void main() {
  runApp(ProviderApp());
}

class ProviderApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Define your Provider here, above MaterialApp
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ColorModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: ScreenA()
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenA extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Thanks for your help :)')),
      body: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        //
        // color: bgColor // - global var removed -
        color: Provider.of<ColorModel>(context).bgColor,
        // ↑ use your Provider state-stored value here ↑
        //
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text('Change background color on this screen'),
            OutlinedButton(
              style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.green[600],
              ),
              child: Text('Go Screen B', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              // Navigator.push returns a Future, must async/await to use return value
              onPressed: () async {
                var result = await Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenB()));
                // note that this context is not Screen A context, but MaterialApp context
                // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66485893/2301224
                print('>>> Button1-onPressed completed, result=$result');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is your state object. Store your state here.
/// Create this once and use anywhere you need.  Don't re-create this unless
/// you want to wipe out all state data you were holding/sharing.
class ColorModel with ChangeNotifier {
  // color is the state info you want to store & share
  Color bgColor = Colors.yellow[100]; // initialized to yellow

  /// Update your state value and notify any interested listeners
  void updateBgColor(Color newColor) {
    bgColor = newColor;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// - removed - replaced with updateBgColor ↑
  /*void updateDisplay() {
    notifyListeners();
  }*/
}

class ScreenB extends StatelessWidget {
  // all fields in StatelessWidgets should be final
  //final int value;  // this value isn't needed
  final List<String> names = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'];
  final List<Color> colors = [Colors.red[100], Colors.green[100], Colors.blue[100]];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Instantiating your model & giving it to Provider to should only happen once per
    /// Widget Tree that needs access to that state. e.g. MaterialApp for this solution
    /// The state object & Provider below was repeated & has been commented out / removed.
    /// This was wiping out any previously stored state and creating a new Provider / Inherited scope
    /// to all children.
    /*return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ColorModel()),
      ],
      child: ,
    );*/
    // - end of duplicate Provider removal -
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen2'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Consumer<ColorModel>(builder: (context, colorModel, child) {
          return DropdownButton(
            //value: value, // this value isn't needed
            hint: Text("Select a color"),
            onChanged: (int value) {
              colorModel.updateBgColor(colors[value]);
              Navigator.pop(context, colors[value]);
            },
            items: [
              DropdownMenuItem(value: 0, child: Text(names[0])),
              DropdownMenuItem(value: 1, child: Text(names[1])),
              DropdownMenuItem(value: 2, child: Text(names[2])),
            ],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I suspected it might be due to the Provider not being high enough up the widget tree. Your explanation in the linked response is very helpful too. Very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just to add - the explanations in the code are really helpful too in explaining how things fit together. Splendid :-)