# How to use a created list in another class?

Tags: list, flutter, widget

When i create a list, i can only use it in the class where i created the list. But in another class i get an error 'undefined name' when i want to use the list. How can i get access to the list?

For example in my code i created a list 'plans' with strings.

```
class _PlanOverviewState extends State<PlanOverview> {
  List<String> plans = ['Plan A', 'Plan B'];

  void addPlan(String neuerPlan) {
    setState(() {
      plans.add(neuerPlan);
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
```

Now I want to output a single string from the list plans in another Widget in the Appbar as title, so the User know where he is.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(plans[i]))
```

How can i get access to the list plans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create & use an `InheritedWidget`-style accessor for your `State` class and then you can access it from any descendant `context`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InheritedWidgetPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InheritedWidgetPageState createState() => _InheritedWidgetPageState();

  static _InheritedWidgetPageState of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.findAncestorStateOfType<_InheritedWidgetPageState>();
}

class _InheritedWidgetPageState extends State<InheritedWidgetPage> {
  List<String> plans = ['Plan A', 'Plan B'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _InheritedWidgetPageState _state = InheritedWidgetPage.of(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_state.plans[0]),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Goto ${_state.plans[1]}'),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PlanPage(1))),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PlanPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;

  PlanPage(this.index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _InheritedWidgetPageState _state = InheritedWidgetPage.of(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_state.plans[index]),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('You are here: ${_state.plans[index]}'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This can be pretty confusing to understand at first, but will make more sense as you get more familiar with [Flutter's declarative framework](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/declarative).

For the above example to work, you need to have a `MaterialApp` ancestor widget, and your `State` class (where you're holding your `plans` state object) needs to be its parent. I explain why on a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66485893/2301224).

Your other option is to use a [State Management package of which there are lots](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options), which can help you simplify access to state objects.