# Flutter could not find the correct Provider above BlocConsumer Widget

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm using `Flutter Bloc` for a project.

This is the structure:

```dart
      MultiBlocProvider(
          providers: [
            BlocProvider<BlocA>(
              create: (context) {
                return BlocA()
                  ..add(FetchEvent());
              },
            ),
            BlocProvider<BlocC>(
              create: (context) {
                return BlocC()..add(FetchEvent());
              },
            ),
          ],
          child: IndexedStack(
            index: _pageNum,
            children: [
              ChildA(),
              ChildB(),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Inside `ChildB` I have a `Navigator.push()` to a `ChildC`, where `BlocC` is being used (`BlocConsumer`), but I'm getting an error,

```
Flutter could not find the correct Provider above BlocConsumer<BlocC> Widget
```

**Edit**
There is a button in `ChildB` that navigates to `ChildC` on pressed.
Like,

```
TextButton( // this code exists inside a scaffold widget
   child: Text("Page C"),
   onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChildC()));
   }
),
```

This is the bloc consumer in `ChildC`

```dart
// Child C
 Scaffold(
      body: BlocConsumer<BlocC, CState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if(state is CSuccessState) {
            return _body();
          } else if (state is CLoadingState || state is CInitState) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else return Center(child: Text("Something went wrong"));
        },
        listener: (context, state) {},

      ),
    );
```

**Edit 2**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66485893/13076945) answer, apparently, this is an issue when using `Navigator.push`. Still, if anyone knows how to solve it in my case, do let me know

Comment: Can you post the code of BlocConsumer?

Comment: You navigate to Child C which uses BlocC? Can you provide the part where you navigate to ChildC

Comment: one possible reason is `ChildC` is not inside `MultiBlocProvider` tree, in this case, consider moving your bloc providers to a higher scope

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provider is scoped.
It means only the subtree of your provider (your child widgets) can access it.
When you push a new page, it pushed it to the `MaterialApp` router (default root router of your app), and your widget tree looks like:

```
MaterialApp
 |- Provider
 |   |- TextButton (with onPressed: () => Navigator.push())
 |- ChildC
```

As you can see, your `ChildC` is not below the `Provider`(s).

---

## 1. Move your providers above your material app

A way to solve it is to move your providers above your `MaterialApp`:

```
Provider
 |- MaterialApp
 |   |- TextButton (with onPressed: () => Navigator.push())
 |   |- ChildC
```

## 2. Use nested routers

You can push your page to a nested router that is below your `Provider`:

```
MaterialApp
 |- Provider
 |   |- Router
 |   |  |- TextButton (with onPressed: () => Navigator.push())
 |   |  |- ChildC
```

## 3. Provide again your `BlockC` above `ChildC` :

```dart
TextButton( // this code exists inside a scaffold widget
   child: Text("Page C"),
   onPressed: () {
      final blockCValue = context.read<BlockC>();
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => Provider<BlockC>.value(
          value: blockCValue,
          child: ChildC(),
        ),
      );
   },
),
```

Comment: How can you send your provider to the other screen without doing it global ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you try to specify? I believe this is what my point `3.` illustrates

Comment: For example, you have ScreenA and ScreenB, i want to use in both the same Provider Bloc, but instead of creating it globally, i create it in the ScreenA, so, i push to the ScreenB, how can re-provide it now in the ScreenB ? Cause i have a problem here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75247028/unhandled-exception-bad-state-cannot-add-new-events-after-calling-close-betw?noredirect=1#comment132782939_75247028

Answer (score 1):

The Navigator's behaviour is expected.

You should replace
`Navigator.push(context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChildC()));`
with

```
Navigator.push(context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (ctx) => BlocProvider.value(value: context.read<BlocC>()), child: ChildC());
```

This will work.