# Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close - Between screens

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have the next architecture :

```dart
ScreenA > ScreenB

/// Here i navigate from ScreenA to ScreenB, so here i create the BlocB that i'm going to use
BlocProvider<BlocB>(
  create: (context) => BlocB(),
  child: const ScreenB(),
),
```

```dart
ScreenB > ScreenC

await Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(
  PageNames.screenC,
  arguments: context.read<BlocB>(),
);

/// Here i navigate from ScreenB to ScreenC, so i re-value the BlocB
BlocProvider<BlocB>.value(
  value: (args as BlocB),
  child: const ScreenC(),
),
```

Here i do the same logic until ScreenD where i'm going to use a BlocListener and do the add event from the BlocB

```dart
ScreenC > ScreenD

await Navigator.pushNamed(
  context,
  PageNames.screenD,
  arguments: context.read<BlocB>(),
);

/// Here i navigate from ScreenC to ScreenD, so i re-value the BlocB
BlocProvider<BlocB>.value(
  value: (args as BlocB),
  child: const ScreenD(),
),
```

The BlocF listener

```dart
return BlocListener<BlocF, BlocFState>(
  listener: (context, state) {
     if (state.status.isSuccess) {
        context.read<BlocB>().add(someEvent()); // error
     }
  },
  child: child...
```

Now, i'm going to use a add event from another Bloc (BlocF for example), now send a status and with its listener, i want to add event from BlocB, but a i have the error :

`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close`

I don't know why if i pass through the screens my Bloc

Comment: why do you always recreate a provider? You can also pass the bloc instance as an argument and use it directly

Comment: I only create it once, in the ScreenB, i only pass it as a argument with value, or value is also create a bloc ?

Answer (score 2):

The error message suggests that the `BlocB` instance being used in the `BlocListener` of `ScreenF` is no longer valid. This can happen if the `BlocB` instance is closed or disposed of when navigating away from `ScreenA`, and then trying to use it again in ScreenD.

###### Possible solutions:

1. Ensure that the `BlocB` instance is not closed or disposed of when navigating away from `ScreenA` by using a `BlocProvider` that is above the entire navigation stack and not just within the individual screens. This way the same `BlocB` instance is always available throughout the navigation stack.
2. Pass the `BlocB` instance as a constructor argument to the next screen, rather than relying on `BlocProvider.value` to re-create it.

Comment: But idk when my BlocB is disposed or close, because i send it in every argument, idk if it's the Navigator or what

Comment: What is weird, is that in the ScreenD i use a BlocSelector of BlocB and it works !