# Could not find the correct Provider above this ListView Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

**Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this StudentsList Widget**

Trying to access the data from the provider package but stuck with this error I tried adding ChangeNotifierProvider to the main dart file but still getting the same error.

Home Screen

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => Students(),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Home"),
      ),
      body: StudentsList(),
    );
  }
}
```

StudentsList File

```
class StudentsList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var studentDataList = Provider.of<Students>(context).studentsList;
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (ctx, item) {
        return ListTile(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: do you use hot reload? if yes, you should stop your project and run it again in order to be able to use `Provider` after adding `ChangeNotifierProvider`

Comment: tried that but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just a syntax error that is creating this issue.
Edited the code in the home screen to :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => Students(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Home"),
        ),
        body: StudentsList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Moving Provider up to a parent, MaterialApp context, allows both Screen A and B to inherit its state/context.

provider(MaterialApp)

> Screen A
> Screen B

check this link : **[Could not find the correct provider above this widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124258/could-not-find-the-correct-provider-above-this-widget)**

and its good to check this link for more details :
**https://flutteragency.com/how-to-resolve-could-not-find-the-correct-provider-above-widget-in-flutter/**