# I try to add new event in table with provider , but the code get error

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, table-calendar

```
import 'package:booking_calendar/utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';

import 'pages/events_example.dart';
import 'package:booking_calendar/pages/multi_example.dart';
import 'package:booking_calendar/pages/complex_example.dart';
import 'package:booking_calendar/pages/basics_example.dart';
import 'package:booking_calendar/pages/range_example.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  initializeDateFormatting().then((_) => runApp(MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'TableCalendar Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: StartPage(),
    );
  }
}

class StartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<EventData>(
      create: (context) => EventData(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Table Calendar'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Basics'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => TableBasicsExample()),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 12.0),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Multiple Selection'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => TableMultiExample()),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

import 'package:booking_calendar/data/event.dart';

/// Example event class.
class EventData extends ChangeNotifier{

  late var kToday = DateTime.now();
  late var kFirstDay = DateTime(kToday.year, kToday.month - 6, kToday.day);
  late var kLastDay = DateTime(kToday.year, kToday.month + 6, kToday.day);

/// Example events.
  ///
  /// Using a [LinkedHashMap] is highly recommended if you decide to use a map.
  late var kEvents = LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<Event>>(
    equals: isSameDay,
    hashCode: getHashCode,
  )..addAll(kEventSource1);

  /// Example events.
  ///
  /// Using a [LinkedHashMap] is highly recommended if you decide to use a map.

// Keep data as List
  late var kEventSource1 = Map.fromIterables(kDay, events);
  List<DateTime> kDay = [DateTime.utc(2023, 6, 6), DateTime.utc(2023, 6, 7)];
  List<List<Event>> events = [
    [Event('Test1'), Event('Test2')],
    [Event('Test3')],
  ];

  void addEvent(Set<DateTime> selectedDays, String newEvents) {
    List<DateTime> kDays = [];
    kDays = selectedDays.toList();
    kDay.addAll(kDays);

    List<Event> event = [];
    var kEvent = Event(newEvents);
    event.add(kEvent);
    events.add(event);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int getHashCode(DateTime key) {
    return key.day * 1000000 + key.month * 10000 + key.year;
  }

  /// Returns a list of [DateTime] objects from [first] to [last], inclusive.
  List<DateTime> daysInRange(DateTime first, DateTime last) {
    final dayCount = last.difference(first).inDays + 1;
    return List.generate(
      dayCount,
          (index) => DateTime.utc(first.year, first.month, first.day + index),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Event{

  // List<DateTime>? eventDate;
  List<List<String>>? eventName;

  final String title;

  @override
  String toString() => title;

  Event(this.title, {this.eventName});
}
```

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'package:booking_calendar/utils.dart';
import 'package:booking_calendar/data/event.dart';


class TableMultiExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TableMultiExampleState createState() => _TableMultiExampleState();
}

class _TableMultiExampleState extends State<TableMultiExample> {

  late String newEvents;
  var eventData = EventData();

  final ValueNotifier<List<Event>> _selectedEvents = ValueNotifier([]);

  // Using a `LinkedHashSet` is recommended due to equality comparison override
  late Set<DateTime> _selectedDays = LinkedHashSet<DateTime>(
    equals: isSameDay,
    hashCode: eventData.getHashCode,
  );

  CalendarFormat _calendarFormat = CalendarFormat.month;
  DateTime _focusedDay = DateTime.now();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _selectedEvents.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  List<Event> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day) {
    // Implementation example
    return eventData.kEvents[day] ??[];
  }

  List<Event> _getEventsForDays(Set<DateTime> days) {
    // Implementation example
    // Note that days are in selection order (same applies to events)
    return [
      for (final d in days) ...?_getEventsForDay(d),
    ];
  }

  void _onDaySelected(DateTime selectedDay, DateTime focusedDay) {
    setState(() {
      _focusedDay = focusedDay;
      // Update values in a Set
      if (_selectedDays.contains(selectedDay)) {
        _selectedDays.remove(selectedDay);
      } else {
        _selectedDays.add(selectedDay);
      }
    });

    _selectedEvents.value = _getEventsForDays(_selectedDays);
  }

  // This is example function used for adding event

  void _showAddDialog() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
              title: const Text("Add Events"),
              content: TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.add_comment,
                    color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide:
                        BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 2.0),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Add new event here.',
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                ),
                onChanged: (String newEvent) {
                  newEvents = newEvent;
                },
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  child: const Text(
                    "Add",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    var provider = Provider.of<EventData>(context, listen: false);
                    provider.addEvent(_selectedDays, newEvents);
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                )
              ],
            ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('TableCalendar - Multi'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        onPressed: _showAddDialog,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TableCalendar<Event>(
            firstDay: eventData.kFirstDay,
            lastDay: eventData.kLastDay,
            focusedDay: _focusedDay,
            calendarFormat: _calendarFormat,
            eventLoader: _getEventsForDay,
            startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
            selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
              // Use values from Set to mark multiple days as selected
              return _selectedDays.contains(day);
            },
            // To display event as number.
            calendarStyle:
                CalendarStyle(markersAlignment: Alignment.bottomRight),
            calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
              markerBuilder: (context, _focusedDay, _selectedEvents) =>
                  _selectedEvents.isNotEmpty
                      ? Container(
                          width: 24,
                          height: 24,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.lightBlue,
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            '${_selectedEvents.length}',
                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        )
                      : null,
            ),
            onDaySelected: _onDaySelected,
            onFormatChanged: (format) {
              if (_calendarFormat != format) {
                setState(() {
                  _calendarFormat = format;
                });
              }
            },
            onPageChanged: (focusedDay) {
              _focusedDay = focusedDay;
            },
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Clear selection'),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _selectedDays.clear();
                _selectedEvents.value = [];
              });
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Expanded(
            child: ValueListenableBuilder<List<Event
            >>(
              valueListenable: _selectedEvents,
              builder: (context, value, _) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: value.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 12.0,
                        vertical: 4.0,
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                      ),
                      child: ListTile(
                        onTap: () => print('${value[index]}'),
                        title: Text('${value[index]}'),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below shows error.

======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown while handling a gesture:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Builder Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that Builder is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
    );
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context, child) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
      }
    );
  }
  ```

If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter

## When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Provider._inheritedElementOf (package:provider/src/provider.dart:343:7)
#1      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:293:30)
#2      _TableMultiExampleState._showAddDialog.. (package:booking_calendar/pages/multi_example.dart:118:45)
#3      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1154:21)
#4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:275:24)
#5      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:654:11)
#6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:311:5)
#7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:244:7)
#8      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:630:9)
#9      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:98:12)
#10     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes. (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:143:9)
#11     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:625:13)
#12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:141:18)
#13     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:127:7)
#14     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:465:19)
#15     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:445:22)
#16     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:331:11)
#17     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:400:7)
#18     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:363:5)
#19     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:320:7)
#20     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:293:9)
#21     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:158:13)
#22     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:382:7)
#23     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:91:31)
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#257e6
debugOwner: GestureDetector
state: possible
won arena
finalPosition: Offset(301.4, 349.1)
finalLocalPosition: Offset(37.1, 26.3)
button: 1
sent tap down

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EobuU.png)

I need to add new event in multi calendar with provider package.

I am a new flutter learner. Please kindly advise to fix this error, Thank you in advance.

Comment: remove ChangeNotifierProvider from StartPage and wrap MaterialApp with ChangeNotifierProvider instead

Comment: [More info on understanding Provider scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66485893/2301224).